# How can I generate a column which is a combination of values from different columns

Tags: t-sql

I have table with following structure.

[image: or]

and I want to generate a row per day and a column per combination of first and second level category. The output should be like:

[image]

Can anybody help me out in writing such query?

Comment: Should A&E be considered the same as, or different from, E&A? If there are multiple rows with the same cat_1/cat_2 combo, do you want the sum(), min(), max(), avg(), something else?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using (t-sql could refer to MS SQL Server or Sybase/SAP ASE) and what version?  what have you tried so far?

Comment: I use SQL Fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I hope the query is self-explanatory enough:

```
INSERT INTO new 
SELECT sold_date
     , IIF( cat_1 = "A" AND cat_2 = "C", sold_price, NULL ) AS 'A&C'
     , IIF( cat_1 = "A" AND cat_2 = "E", sold_price, NULL ) AS 'A&E'
     , IIF( cat_1 = "B" AND cat_2 = "D", sold_price, NULL ) AS 'B&D'
  FROM old
 ORDER BY sold_date ASC
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, because my table has around 50 rows is there any other solution for this problem

Comment: So your source table with `cat_1` and `cat_2` will be transformed into the table with 50+ additional columns?

Comment: Yes, I exactly want a row per day, and a column per combination of first and second level category.

Comment: I suspect that the resulting table will be a sparse one where for each long row the one or none column will contain the price while all other columns will be NULLs. It seems to be a bad design or even an XY-problem and my advise is to revise the approach.